# Excel If Else condition issue

Tags: excel-formula

I have a simple `IF-ELSE` formula set in excel which somehow not giving me the desired result. I am putting an if-else condition in one of the columns which should result in me the value of other columns based on the condition.

Here is the formula

```
=IF(G25<15,C25,B25)
```

However, it is always going into the `B25` no matter that. Please help me to understand the issue with the formula.

Comment: The issue might not be in your formula, but rather in your _data_.  Please show us some sample data for the `B`, `G`, and `G` columns.

Comment: What data type of column `G25`? Is it `Number`?

Comment: Yes, It is a number. Here you go: B25(=minus(12,F25)*1.75) = 12.25 C25(=minus(11,F25)*1.75) = 10.5. F25 = 5 G25 = 8 Every time it is giving me 12.25.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen G25 is text. here it is    =Text(H25,"d")

Comment: Thank you, Tim. You gave me the right hint. I converted it to Number and it is working fine now.